# Как это тире оправдать?

Tags: тире

Можно это тире тем оправдать, что здесь можно подставить перед *бывает* *это* или, например, *такое*.

> Разынтересовалася она мною **—** бывает.

Comment: Какова грамматика этого предложения? Оно сложное, простое, осложненное? С этого надо начинать выбор знаков, а иначе о чем говорить. От грамматики зависит дальнейшее решение, которое должно соответствовать Розенталю или ПАС.  Так какое это предложение?

Comment: Сложное бессоюзное.

Comment: Прекрасно! Мы уже начали работать сами. Пусть будет БСП, а отношение между частями предложения – присоединительные.  Это факт и авторский комментарий по его поводу. Такие отношения можно обозначить только тире, но никак не двоеточием или запятой. Вот и подставлять ничего не пришлось, простейшее решение.